# How to send an image (byte[]) from a servlet to an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, css, jsp, servlets

I have an image in the form of byte[] in a servlet. I want to send this image to an html (or a JSP page) page by forwarding request to that html (or JSP). Please tell me how would i do that, and how that image would be displayed on HTML page.

Comment: You *could* use a "data:" URL and embed the whole image into HTML, but if it is big and cacheable, maybe a normal image tag (that does a separate request) is better.

Comment: hey. can you tell me the exact TAG. suppose in my servlet i used.  byte[] image; /*store an image in the variable image*/ request.setAttribute("myimage",image);  /*now forward the request*/. Now which tag and how to use that in order to display that image.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the `byte[]` data to an image and provide the HTML page a URL to the produced image. Here is a simple example of the conversion:

```
BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(bytes));
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yeah. Thats an alternative,  i figured out this one earlier. But is there any other way out. As for this thing my server will have a large number of temporary files.

Comment: Another approach would be to convert the image (or byte[]) to Base64 string and display the string in HTML img tag. But again, depending on the size of your image this string may grow out of bounds and slow down your site. Yet another approach is to find a smart way to deal with temp files and delete them as soon as you are done etc.

Comment: Why do you need a BufferedImage? The browser needs just the raw bytes, you don't want to render it on the server. No need to load it into memory on the server.

Comment: Yes, but how do you plan on transporting raw bytes to the browser/client and then converting these raw bytes to an image on client side. There are also compression algorithms that you could use on the server side to decrease the size of the raw byte stream.

Comment: And also, say i have to do the converse i.e. i have an <input type="image"> in my html, how would i transfer this image to the servlet in the form of byte[].

Comment: okay. i need a bufferedImage because it is stored in the database of object BLOB.

Comment: I would just stay away from `byte[]` communication between the browser client and the server in either direction. Try to look at other approaches such as converting an image to a string, or using a file upload form etc. With HTML5 API, it's generally possible to convert an image to Base64 and submit it via AJAX but I believe earlier versions of Safari do not support this functionality.

Comment: There is a special prefix. Search "display base64 image in HTML". It's very simple.

Comment: Finally its done..  Thanks to Both of you.. You made my day..  :-):-)